# Why Firebase push notification show notification automatically if i not open Notification in OnMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for push notifications and I have one issue. When the application is in the foreground that onMessageReceived call and I show notification but when the app in background or kill then onMessageReceived not called and my own notification method not called but notification show when content.
Mean if I send a notification from the console with the title "Hello" and onMessageReceived I show a notification with the dummy title "My Notification".
When app in the foreground that notification show "My Notification" title but when in the background and kills then shows "Hello".
If I remove notification generate code from onMessageReceived then notification also popup.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended, notification messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived callback only when your app is in the foreground. If your app is in the background or closed then the system tray will receive the message and read body and title from the notification block and shows the default message and title in the notification bar, and any data from that message is passed to the intent that is launched as a result of the user tapping on the notification.

**Reference Link:**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive